# Background color on content limit

Tags: java, android

I have an activity with a layout which covers about a half screen.

this is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/greetingTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sir,"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dailyStatusTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/greetingTextView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Dont forget!" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Reminder_title_TV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Tiltle"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
<!--         android:textColor="#ff33b5e5" -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Reminder_text_TV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Reminder_title_TV"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
<!--         android:textColor="#ff33b5e5" -->




 <Button
    android:id="@+id/not_now_BT"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text=" Not Now "
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Reminder_text_TV"
    />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/OK_BT"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" OK "
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/not_now_BT"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Reminder_text_TV"
    />
```

How can i set a background color for only the space in which i have content in my screen?

For example if 70% of my screen have content i want only this part of the screen to have background color.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/greetingTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Sir,"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dailyStatusTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/greetingTextView"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:text="Dont forget!" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Reminder_title_TV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Tiltle"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
<!--         android:textColor="#ff33b5e5" -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/Reminder_text_TV"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Reminder_title_TV"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"

    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>
<!--         android:textColor="#ff33b5e5" -->


</LinearLayout>

<!-- End your linear layout here if this is 70 percent -->


 <Button
    android:id="@+id/not_now_BT"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text=" Not Now "
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Reminder_text_TV"
    />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/OK_BT"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text=" OK "
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/not_now_BT"
    android:layout_below="@+id/Reminder_text_TV"
    />
```